# How to save JSON in DB - laravel 8

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, request

I'll have JSON and try to disassemble and save it in database:

```
{
    "token": "f56445c24ad84e9c452f3ca6ef91e90beb2aef21",
    "participant": "ZuP0rsny3MhqLC0",
    "data": {
        "orgs": [{
            "org1": {
                "attribute": [{
                    "name": "val",
                    "inn": "val",
                    "kpp": "val"
                }],
                "tickets": [{
                    "ticket1": [{
                        "account_uid": "val",
                        "created_at": "val",
                        "title": "val",
                        "text": "val",
                        "status": "val",
                        "priority": "val",
                        "fullname": "val",
                        "workaddr": "val",
                        "phone": "val",
                        "email": "val",
                        "workstart": "val",
                        "workend": "val",
                        "dispetcher": "val",
                        "responsible": "val",
                        "closed_at": "val",
                        "file": "val"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I'll try to save it to db with using use Illuminate\Http\Request(Request $request), but can't given access to array org1 and ticket.
Misstake:

```
Undefined array key &quot;org1&quot;
```

Which way to move?
Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the json into an array:

```
$json_array = json_decode($your_json, true);
```

Access the element you want:

```
$org1 = $json_array['data']['orgs']['org1'];
```

And if you want to convert to json:

```
$org1 = json_encode($org1);
```

Comment: Thnx, 4 answer, but using your way i'll have mistake: ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: Just tried, it works well on my side. Share your code please

Comment: Maybe you should implement some validation in your controller. It seems the array does not exist

Comment: json in topick start, and function to try output: look like yor example^

Comment: public function test(Request $request)  {
      
      $json_array = json_decode($request->data, true);
      $org1 = $json_array['data']['orgs']['org1'];
      dd ($org1);
      
    }

Comment: What do you get when you `dd($request->data)`

Comment: return $request['data'] - give me arry with data. But i'm haven't decode() it/ Illl hve misstake - TypeError: json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array

Comment: try like that: `public function test(Request $request) { $json_array = json_decode(json_encode($request->data), true); $org1 = $json_array['data']['orgs']['org1']; dd ($org1); }`

Comment: I'l resolve it, my json is some stupid and make more array. I'll fix him.

Comment: i'm delete  [ ] from request end have acces to data like this dd($request->data['orgs']['org1']['tickets']['ticket1']);

Answer (score 0):

dd() output:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "orgs" => array:1 [
      0 => array:1 [
        "org1" => array:1 [
          0 => array:2 [
            "attribute" => array:1 [
              0 => array:3 [
                "name" => "Из json"
                "inn" => "88888111"
                "kpp" => "11188888"
              ]
            ]
            "tickets" => array:1 [
              0 => array:1 [
                "ticket1" => array:1 [
                  0 => array:14 [
                    "account_uid" => "UKP2010001002"
                    "created_at" => "2021-13-07"
                    "title" => "Из json"
                    "text" => "Из json"
                    "status" => "1"
                    "priority" => "2"
                    "fullname" => "Вася Джейсонович"
                    "workaddr" => "дом улица фонарь"
                    "phone" => "+791478562548"
                    "email" => "vasya@mail.ru"
                    "workstart" => "вечером"
                    "workend" => "утром"
                    "dispetcher" => "Матрёна Петровна"
                    "responsible" => "Гайдай Пётр"
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```